# ASP.NET Identity - 'log out'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I've been following this article in order to get started with ASP.NET Identity:
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api

I'm logging in using the method shown in the article (i.e. using the token endpoint to get a bearer token). However, I'm unclear on what I need to do to then 'log out'?

Answer (score 1):

You just stop to send the bearer token together with your consecutive requests. There is no explicit log out.

Comment: Thanks. So presumably I need to endeavour to keep bearer tokens a secret? (e.g. enforce HTTPS). Because otherwise, a created bearer token will provide irrevocable access until it expires. The 'AccountController' is confusing me too - why is there a Login and Logout method here?

Comment: There are other types of oauth control flow which could possibly involve Logout.